# C#: Replace Certain Characters if they are the First Character of the String Using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace the following characters with space + same character only if they are the first character of the string:

```
"-"
"+"
"="
```

eg.

```
"+hello" should become " +hello"
"-first-second" should become " -first-second"
```

Comment: you want to append the string to a whitespace if the first item is in your character list?

Comment: add space to them if they are -, + or =

Comment: does it have to be a regex?

Comment: `if (s.StartsWith("-") || s.StartsWith("+") || s.StartsWith("=")) s = " " + s;`?

Comment: i have a solution using conditional operation but I just want to see how regex would solve the same problem.

Comment: If you have some code as you say, please post it so that we do not double the effiorts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-regex approach for this task is more appropriate:

```
if (s.StartsWith("-") || s.StartsWith("+") || s.StartsWith("="))
     s = string.Format(" {0}", s);
```

Or a regex approach can be used if you want to further expand this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("-hello", @"^([-+=])", " $1");
```

The regex:

- `^` - Assert the position at the beginning of the string
- `([-+=])` - match and capture the `-` or `+` or `=` symbol

In the replacement string, we are using a [back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `$1` to the captured text.

See a [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%5B-%2B%3D%5D)&i=-hello&r=%20%241).

Comment: Thanks for the regex solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("^[-+=]");
string text = "+x" //your Text goes here
if (rgx.IsMatch(text))
{
    text = " " + text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex solution

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
var startChars = new List<string> { "+", "-", "=" };
if(startChars.Contains(text.First())
{
   text = $" {text.Substring(1,text.Length-1)}";
}
```